# Self-update a phar archive?

Tags: php, io, updates, phar

I'm planning on creating a bunch of PHP scripts in a phar archive (for easy deployment) and allowing it to self-update from a known repository.

How should a phar archive, on a live website, update itself? Not update its contents, but just replacing itself (from a `new.phar` previously downloaded to `/tmp` or something) would be enough.

I'm specifically concerned about pitfalls on "replacing myself" in PHP, also considering requests could be underway (the script will primarily be called from the web, by AJAX).

Comment: I don't know if there's anything specific to phars that could complicate things, but I'd just go with first verifying the new phar works by adding a --version or some such parameter and calling it. Then, move the current file to a new location, move the new file in, delete the old file.

Comment: @OddEssay I actually forgot to mention, but my main worry is about web requests, not calling the phat by command-line. My reason for making it a phar is just because it's so elegant, but I'd necessarily have to replace it while requests to the live server could be underway. Ideally I'd like it if PHP would use a memory copy of the old phar for the requests started before the copy, but I don't know if it does that or not.

Comment: Generally with normal PHP web requests, everything is compiled then run from memory so if you change the source files it'll only affect new requests even if the processes from the old file are still running. - Also, using move rather than copy means the transfer time would be minimal.

Comment: That said, if you're creating something modular that you want updating in a managed fashion, you should really look at using composer and deploying it as a module :o)

Comment: @OddEssay Never looked at composer. Doesn't it require composer to be present in the server? Ideally I'd like to tell my script user's to just drop the .phar file there and go to its URL in the browser to configure. Also, what you say about pre-compilation makes sense for .php files, but are .phar files also pre-compiled that way?

Answer (score 2):

You can check how composer does self update:

https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Command/SelfUpdateCommand.php

But like @OddEssay said it would probably be better to use composer as package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Distributing CLI PHP App with Ease article](http://moquet.net/blog/distributing-php-cli/).

There is also mentioned [PHP-Phar-Update package](https://github.com/herrera-io/php-phar-update), that handle PHAR self-updating.

For implementation example, you can check [Self-update command of PhpDocumentor](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/blob/92961aee0d17b508fbe0e4dc45b0f546ebca0e1b/src/phpDocumentor/Command/Phar/UpdateCommand.php)